# Date subtraction in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I want to subtract minute from `NOW()` and the value of "how many minutes" I am reading from another table:

```
SELECT * FROM A, B 
WHERE 
   A.entity_type_id = B.entity_type_id  
   AND A.status = 'PENDING'  
   AND A.request_time < (NOW() - INTERVAL B.retry_interval MINUTE) 
   AND A.retry_count >= B.retry_allowed_count
```

Here the problem is `B.retry_interval` is fetched from another table, while normally the queries like these are `A.request_time < (NOW() - INTERVAL '10  MINUTE')`

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Multiply the interval by `interval '1 minute'`

```
SELECT *
FROM A, B 
WHERE 
   A.entity_type_id = B.entity_type_id  
   AND A.status = 'PENDING'  
   AND A.request_time < NOW() - B.retry_interval * INTERVAL '1 minute'
   AND A.retry_count >= B.retry_allowed_count
```

Answer (score 1):

I know its quite old enough, but here what i do. Btw my postgres version is 9.4.18.

try using interval data type. Convert the number from column to sting and concat it.

```
   SELECT * 
   FROM A, B WHERE 
   A.entity_type_id = B.entity_type_id  
   AND A.status = 'PENDING'  
   AND A.request_time < (NOW() - concat(B.retry_interval::text,'minute')::interval
   AND A.retry_count >= B.retry_allowed_count
```

Thanks to my coworker who find "interval" data type